# Oracle JDBC URL when instance and scheam and hostname provided

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc

**How does the oracle JDBC url look like when the following details are provided.**

```
Host: localhost; 
port 1521
Instance: URB
Schema: CRBDBA
```

**The following is the URL I am using.**

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:CRBDBA
```

**Error, saying no sid is found**

How to involve the **instance** in the jdbc url?

Comment: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/URB and then set userName to CRBDBA

Comment: They provided me with two more details (username and password). Where we should specify the schema in the url

Comment: You can't set the schema in the URL. The username **is** the schema in Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name got it. Why it is not working when we use the jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:URB,   i mean what makes the difference in / and : here

Comment: The syntax `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:URB`  is deprecated. The correct syntax would be:  `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/URB`  assuming `URB` is indeed the service name. See the manual for details: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/urls.htm#BEIDHCBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct URL that are working for me are the following.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/URB
```

And also the following

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:CRBDBA:@localhost:1521/URB
```